# How to ask additional questions in someone else's question?

Tags: discussion, support

So I am new to Stack Overflow and have managed to muster up 38 reputation. I found a partial solution to my problem in a question that was asked previously. But however I still have this small query that I need to know for the answer to fully work for me. But as I only have 38 rep, I cannot comment anywhere and it feels wrong to present my question in the answer section. Is there anyway to get me out of this fix.

Comment: Yup. Earn 12 more reputation points.

Comment: Easier said than done. But thanks anyways

Comment: No. Not for follow on questions, @ShadowWizard.

Comment: @Oded OP mentioned comments.

Comment: @Sha - " I still have this small query that I need to know " - to me that means they have follow on questions. That they want to ask them in comments doesn't mean that's the right thing to do.

Comment: I am not fully acquainted to the terminology of the Stackoverflow but i was trying to follow on questions as pointed out by @Oded. I assumed that the only way to do it would be presenting my question on the comments section

Comment: If you ask a question, make sure to clearly state how answers from the previous question did/did not help.  If you don't, people may vote to close it as a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't ask follow on questions in comments.

You ask a new question. You reference the original post (link to it) and ask for the clarification you need, explaining why the answer/s don't do that.

Comment: great. I will try this.thank you for your response